# C# reading and accessing xml tables with same name

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have an XML file as in the example: [XML Example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml)
But when I read it with C# to a dataset I cannot access all CD contents.
I Use the code below

```
ds.ReadXml(sFilePathAndFileName);  //Read Xml file to Dataset            
public void GetTitle()
{
    sTitle = ds.Tables["CD"].Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString();
}
```

I want to access to a specific CD content. For example the third one.
I know I can access with the row number if all content is row. But sometimes it can be another table. So CD is a table and there is a nested table in it. I want to access the deepest table's element.

How can I do this?

Comment: I didn't see any samples of nested tables.  Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Overall, it's always better if you know the structure of your XML completely and iterate through it in a logical manner. Otherwise you might get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = @"https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TITLE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ARTIST", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("COUNTRY", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("COMPANY", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PRICE", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("YEAR", typeof(int));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

            foreach (XElement cd in doc.Descendants("CD"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)cd.Element("TITLE"),
                    (string)cd.Element("ARTIST"),
                    (string)cd.Element("COUNTRY"),
                    (string)cd.Element("COMPANY"),
                    (decimal)cd.Element("PRICE"),
                    (int)cd.Element("YEAR")
                });
            }

            string[] titles = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("TITLE")).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with Linq, minimal code, easy to understand:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILE_PATH);
    //deepest cd element at index 3
    var deepestCD = doc.Descendants("CD").Skip(2)
                        .First(or => !or.Descendants("CD").Any());
    //deepest CD element's title
    var deepestCdTitle = deepestCD.Element(XName.Get("TITLE"));
```

It means:
Get The descendatans of XML with `CD` name, and get the THIRD element that has no descendant.

You can also write it as:

```
    Console.WriteLine(deepestCdTitle);
```